# She felt the truth in his words, perhaps because

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

1. She felt the truth in his words, **perhaps** because their souls had touched when they first met the day before.
2. She felt the truth in his words, because their souls had touched when they first met the day before.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)? In other words, what would be the function of "perhaps" in (1)? Is the speaker of (1) not sure about the reason for which she felt the truth in his words?
Also, can I use some other word like *possibly* or *maybe* in place of *perhaps*?

Comment: 'Perhaps' expresses a degree of speculation. Have you looked for 'perhaps' in a dictionary?

Comment: Speculation about what is my question.

Comment: Speculation about whether she felt the truth in his words because 'their souls had touched' the day before, or whether it was for some other reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as noted in the comments, "perhaps because" is a construction that applies uncertainty to the reason that follows that word "because".

Both of the words "possibly" and "maybe" work as well. "Perhaps" is the most formal or even poetic-sounding of the three, and "maybe" sounds rather banal and conversational, so the author's choice of the word "perhaps" is unsurprising.

Comment: We could perhaps interpret 'their souls had touched' to mean 'she had become infatuated or obsessed with him', and --perhaps-- this was why she was inclined to 'feel the truth in his words' (believe anything he said).